# Counting the number of diagonals?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

In a heptagon not more than two diagonals intersect at any point other than the vertices, then the number of points of intersection of the diagonals is (excluding the vertices of this heptagon)....???

Comment: Is the heptagon convex?

Comment: Yes can take it...take it as regular

Comment: And you wnat to count only intersections *inside* the polygon (ie. without prolonging the diagonals)?

Comment: yes Mr.Hagen von Eitzen...i will rephrase it..counting the point of intersection in the inner region of a regular heptagon..i believe its regular.so there's no point in writing inner region but to emphasize it

Answer (score 2):

There are $7$ diagonals where the endpoints are two edges apart (resp. five edges if counted the other way round)  and $7$ diagonals where they are three edges apart (resp. four edges the other way round).
Each such diagonal intersects precisely those diagonals inside the heptagon that have one endpoint on one side and one on the other side of the given diagonal. There are $1\cdot 4$ such diagonals for the first type and $2\cdot 3$ for the secind type of diagonal. 
In total this gives $7\cdot4+7\cdot6=70$ intersections, but each is counted twice, so the answer is:
$$35.$$
The general answer for odd(!) $n$ would be
$$ \frac n2 \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-3}2}k(n-k-2)$$
by a similar argument.

Comment: the answer is 49....

Comment: Are we only counting intersections inside the heptagon?

Comment: Yes in the inner region Ishan Banerjee

Comment: Yes, but if you only consider the inner region, the answer is 35, whereas if you consider all of them, it's 49.

Answer (score 1):

They are $^7C_2-7 =14$ diagonals. For each diagonal, there are $6$ diagonals which meet the diagonal at a point on the heptagon. There are $14-6-1=7$ diagonals which meet it on a point not on the heptagon. So the answer is $14\times \frac{7}{2}$